# nginx location block with php says "No input file specified."

Tags: nginx

i have been at this for hours. i am trying to make the nginx error pages php enabled and in a set directory yet i keep getting `No input file specified.` all of the errors haave their own dedicated php file in`/var/www/api/errorcodes/`. my code so far:

```
    error_page 400 /errorcodes/400.php;
    error_page 401 /errorcodes/401.php;
    error_page 403 /errorcodes/403.php;
    error_page 404 /errorcodes/404.php;
    error_page 500 /errorcodes/500.php;
    error_page 502 /errorcodes/502.php;
    error_page 504 /errorcodes/504.php;
    location ^~ /errorcodes/ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        alias /var/www/api/errorcodes/;
        internal;
    }
```

this code is located in a config file in `/usr/local/nginx/conf/errorpage.conf` and being called from the host files with the line `include /usr/local/nginx/conf/errorpage.conf;`

Comment: Replace `alias /var/www/api/errorcodes/;` with `root /var/www/api;`

Comment: thank you so much! can you make that an answer so i can mark it as correct? =)